# intellij, switch off ascii handling for properties

Tags: java, intellij-idea, utf-8, ascii, properties-file

Unfortunatelly I am not able to find an option in Intellij which will enable me to show ascii escaped characters in properties-files (*.properties) (UTF-8) for translations, meaning intellij automagically always shows the result of the escaped characters, but I need to confirm the escapeings without the use of an external viewer (vi, mate, etc).

Also it would be nice for the diff viewer in intellij to actually show the changes towards escaped characters.

Here is an example for the escaped string:

```
key=Nak\u0142ad
```

Intellij is always showing it like this:

```
key=Nakład
```

Even when opening the *.properties files in text editor mode, the strings are escaped...

Edit: Im am using

IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.2
Build #IU-145.972, built on May 14, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_73-b02 x86_64
JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation

Comment: What kind of file and can you provide a section of said code/file? I'm curious to see what kind of escaping you are talking about. Assuming its \n and \t? Or something more like: decimal: &#65; hex: &#x0041; javascript: \u0041 ?

Comment: ...added an example. I am talking about properties-files for translations

Comment: What is the extension of the file you are using? And do you know the mode of the file is in? I created a `foo.properties` and it worked fine for me. I'm running intellij 15.0.6. What version of intellij are you running?

Comment: Are you able to actually see the  escaped string, in my example "key=Nak\u0142ad" after editing and in diff mode?

Comment: I think I found what you need. I'll post an answer

Comment: added the answer and just added some screenshots. Let me know if this works for you. I'm on a mac using 15.0.6. I assume if you are on a different version that you'll find something similar. If you were the upvote, please accept the answer too :)

Comment: when you search for file encoding in preferences, what do you get? can you share a screenshot of that too? also are you windows or mac?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/configuring-encoding-for-properties-files.html, click on InteeliJ menu then go to Preferences (mac directions). Then in the upper left search for "file encoding" then you should see your project files on the right. Browse to your property file on the right, then click on it and look at the bottom right for a check box that says "Transparent native-to-ascii conversion" make sure that is unchecked.

These are screen shots from my intellij on my mac. I'm running intellij 15.0.6.

[image]

[image]

Comment: After Restarting Intellij, this was the solution.